# Updating mirrors in composer.lock?

Tags: composer-php, toran-proxy

Is there a way to update the .lock file regarding mirrors, without updating versions?

I've started using toran, but it appears `composer install` is still using github for installing.

`composer update` updated some libraries, but many of the ones I'm using have not had a version change, and their entry in the .lock appears to be unchanged by the addition of a mirror.

Answer (score 1):

To force Composer into reevaluating all of its install history for a project you should delete `vendor/composer/installed.json`, which is the internal cache file for what is installed and how. If you remove it and then `composer install` it will re-evaluate and reprocess the entire installation according to the settings in `composer.json` and the state in `composer.lock`.

Comment: 'rm -r vendor ~/.cache ~/.composer/cache; composer clear-cache; composer install -vv' still looks like it is going to github rather than toran for the packages that do not have mirror entries in the .lock file.